# How to get xml data contract serializer to ignore base class property when serializing derived class

Tags: c#, xml, datacontractserializer

I have a base class which is xml serializable, and decorated with [DataContract].  It is not mine, and I can't alter it.

I have a derived class that is mine.  And I want to override one property in the base class in my derived class.  That property in the base class is decorated with [DataMember].

It looks (schematically) like this:

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract(Namespace="http://someone-else.com/DataContracts/Shared/Stuff/")]
public class SomeoneElseBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class MyDerived: SomeoneElseBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public new string Type
    {
        get => MyTransformMethod(base.Type);
        set => base.Type = value;
    }
}
```

When an instance of MyDerived is serialized using the Data Contract Serializer for Json, it works exactly as I expected.  The serialized Json has exactly one property named "Type", and it holds the value that is transformed in the way I need it to be.

However, when an instance of MyDerived is serialized using the Data Contract Serializer for XML, it is a little more complicated.  The resulting xml has two elements named "Type", one with the namespace "http://someone-else.com/DataContracts/Shared/Stuff/", and one with no specified namespace.  I would like to get serialized xml that does NOT have the base class element for "Type" on the namespace, just the derived class.

Is this possible?  How?

Comment: You need xmlinclude : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @jdweng - thanks - and looking at the documentation, I don't think you are wrong.  Yet my code using the Data Contract Serializer for XML does not user XmlInclude, and works fine.  I wonder if the vanilla (not Data Contract) XML serializer needs XmlInclude, but the Data Contract Serializer does not?  Just guessing.

Comment: When you have an inherited class the XmlSerializer adds a type attribute to the xml.  Serialize works.  The issue is with deserialize of knowing which inherited class is being used.  So the XmlInclude is a lookup for deserialize to use to lookup the inherited class.  The element name is the base class and the type attribute is the inherited class.

Comment: Thanks again @jdweng OK, I get how that would work if I had control over deserialization, but I am trying to use this as the output of restful service, and so I have no control over the deserializer portion.  Without having control of the base class, and also having no control over the deserialization, I want to force the serialization to NOT include the overridden base class property.

Comment: You would have to write your own custom serialize.  The serialize has rules and the Type is a rule for inherited classes.  You can change a xml/class mapping by using [XmlRoot("tagname")] above the class but not sure this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks - I was worried I might have to customize.  Yuck.  Thanks though!